# Write-Progress displaying outside of console buffer

Tags: powershell

I have a script which calls out to an external program ([SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)) for each file in a directory.  I'm calling [`Write-Progress`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849902.aspx) before each call to SoX, but the progress bar is pushed off the top of the console buffer by the output of SoX (regardless of the size of the console).  Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Here's the script:

```
$audioFiles = ls -Exclude *.ps1 | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } 
foreach ($audioFile in $audioFiles)
{
    $i++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Transforming Audio" -Status $audioFile.Name -PercentComplete (($i / @($audioFiles).length) * 100)
    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-0\sox.exe' "$audioFile" ('Fast/' + $audioFile.Name) -S -G tempo -s 1.3 
}

Write-Progress -Activity "Transforming Audio" -PercentComplete 100 -Completed

[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”) 
[windows.forms.messagebox]::show(“All done!”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set the same console cursor position before the sox output ?
please try

```
$audioFiles = ls -Exclude *.ps1 | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } 
foreach ($audioFile in $audioFiles){
    $i++
    Write-Progress -Activity "Transforming Audio" -Status $audioFile.Name -PercentComplete (($i / @($audioFiles).length) * 100)

    # get windows height 
    $y=[int]($host.ui.rawui.WindowSize.Height -5)
    # will set cursor position to bottom of the screen 
    $Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Coordinates 2,$y 
    #clear current line
    $sbOut = new-object System.Text.Stringbuilder
    (0.. $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width)|%{$sbOut.append(' ')} |out-Null
    write-Host $sbOut.toString() -NoNewline

    & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-0\sox.exe' "$audioFile" ('Fast/' + $audioFile.Name) -S -G tempo -s 1.3 
    }
Write-Progress -Activity "Transforming Audio" -PercentComplete 100 -Completed
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Windows.Forms”) 
[windows.forms.messagebox]::show(“All done!”)
```

you could also redirect sox output to a file or if you dont care about sox output just redirect it to out-null :

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-0\sox.exe' "$audioFile" ('Fast/' + $audioFile.Name) -S -G tempo -s 1.3 | out-null
```

Comment: It was still pushed off the top of the console.  I'd thought about redirecting output to a file, but SoX shows progress for each file that it works on, so it's doing the per-file progress that I want, while `Write-Progress` is giving the overall progress.

Comment: sorry i dont understand your needs, do you care about the sox's output ? do you have a sample ?

Comment: Yes, I do want to see the SoX output (it is dynamically-updating progress info).  The output looks like https://gist.github.com/4118739

Comment: just replace the line `(0.. $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width)|%{$sbOut.append(' ')} |out-Null` with `(0.. 10)|%{$sbOut.append('`n')} |out-Null`  to clear more lines

Comment: It looks like SoX is clearing out the buffer above its output, so regardless of how many lines I add, they're ignored once SoX takes over.

Comment: i've downloaded sox and tested with powershell v2 and it seems to work like you expect...

Comment: If it's the first command you execute, then it doesn't happen.  It's only when the buffer already has content that SoX is able to push it all away...  (BTW, really appreciate all of the time you're spending looking into this with me)